# How use two Foreign Keys inside Single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables on database,'**locations**' & '**sales_person**'.inside the '**location**' table there are two columns name "location_from" & "location_to".Those 2 tables include primary keys of **sales_person** table as Foreign Keys.

[image]

the problem is, how to get both sales person names from **sales_person** table using **only one** query?

Answer (score 2):

Join `sales_person` table twice with `location` to get names for `location_to`  and `location_from`

```
select t.name,f.name
from location l
join sales_person t on l.location_to = t.id
join sales_person f on l.location_from = f.id
```

I assume you have `name` column in your `sales_person` table

Comment: @IshanDarshana see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use union for single query.

```
select lt.name from location l join sales_person as lt on l.location_to = lt.id
UNION ALL
select lf.name from location l join sales_person as lf on l.location_from = lf.id
```